# Select Multiple Values From Xml Document in One Statement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to select the values from two adjacent xml nodes at the same time using

```
var values =
            xDoc.Element("root")
                .Elements("model")
                .Where(x => x.Element("modelName").Value == modelType.ToString())
                .Elements("directory")
                .Select(x => new { x.Element("directoryName").Value,
                               x.Element("taskName").Value });
```

I'm getting red squiggles under the `.Value`s saying "Duplicate anonymous type property name 'Value'.
Here is the xml

```
    <root>
  <model>
    <modelName>Model1</modelName>
    <directory>
      <directoryName>Dir1</directoryName>
      <taskName>Task1</taskName>
    </directory>
  </model>
  <model>
    <modelName>Model2</modelName>
    <directory>
      <directoryName>FirstValue</directoryName>
      <taskName>SecondValue</taskName>
    </directory>
  </model>
</root>
```

I want to extract Dir1 and Task1 or FirstValue and SecondValue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use casting elements to string instead of accessing their `Value` property. Because if element is missing (e.g. for `Model1` you don't have `taskName` element) then you will get `NullReferenceException`.

```
var values = from m in xDoc.Root.Elements("model")
             where (string)m.Element("modelName") == modelType.ToString()
             let d = m.Element("directory")
             select new {
                Directory = (string)d.Element("directoryName"),
                Task = (string)d.Element("taskName")
             };
```

Also I find declarative (query) syntax more readable than lambda syntax (matter of taste). You can also use XPath to make query even more compact:

```
string xpath = String.Format("root/model[modelName='{0}']/directory", modelType);
var values = from d in xdoc.XPathSelectElements(xpath)
             select new {
                 Directory = (string)d.Element("directoryName"),
                 Task = (string)d.Element("taskName")
             };
```

Comment: @reggaeguitar your code throws exception for sample xml you provided. Try it with `modelType = "Model1"`

Comment: It's in a method where you have to provide an enum for the model type, e.g ModelType.Model2 which will turn into the string "Model2" on the ToString() call. I just filled in the xml.

Comment: +1 for the xDoc.Root property, I was not aware of that.

Comment: @reggaeguitar thanks! BTW I added xpath sample which might by interesting to you

Comment: Very cool! I ran it through my unit tests and it passed with flying colors.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, you just need to name the properties in the anonymous type

```
var values =
            xDoc.Element("root")
                .Elements("model")
                .Where(x => x.Element("modelName").Value == modelType.ToString())
                .Elements("directory")
                .Select(x => new { Directory = x.Element("directoryName").Value,
                                   Task = x.Element("taskName").Value });
```